# Dummy variables and interactions

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, interaction, linear-model, categorical-encoding

To avoid perfect multicollinearity, a common practice is to drop one dummy variable when encoding categorical variables in a linear regression model (avoiding dummy variable trap). I am using [this examle](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/example_formulas.html) in Python, but my question is a general question.

My question is, if we need to consider the interactions between a categorical variable and a numerical variable (`Region:Wealth` in the example below, where `Region` is categorical), how do we consider the effect for the ommited dummy variable.

In the example below, I've used the StatsModels from Python, but R works the same way.

```
model = smf.ols(formula='Lottery ~ Literacy + Wealth + Region + Region:Wealth', data=df)
```

The summary of such a model looks like this:

```
OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                Lottery   R-squared:                       0.351
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.263
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     3.999
Date:                Thu, 13 Feb 2020   Prob (F-statistic):           0.000215
Time:                        16:52:37   Log-Likelihood:                -374.47
No. Observations:                  85   AIC:                             770.9
Df Residuals:                      74   BIC:                             797.8
Df Model:                          10                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
======================================================================================
                         coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept             31.1510     15.589      1.998      0.049       0.089      62.213
Region[T.E]           -8.3107     17.462     -0.476      0.636     -43.105      26.483
Region[T.N]           -6.9277     15.041     -0.461      0.646     -36.897      23.042
Region[T.S]           -1.9901     16.235     -0.123      0.903     -34.339      30.359
Region[T.W]            6.1831     17.155      0.360      0.720     -27.999      40.365
Literacy              -0.1477      0.224     -0.659      0.512      -0.594       0.299
Wealth                 0.5923      0.250      2.367      0.021       0.094       1.091
Region[T.E]:Wealth    -0.1750      0.326     -0.537      0.593      -0.824       0.474
Region[T.N]:Wealth    -0.0388      0.406     -0.095      0.924      -0.849       0.771
Region[T.S]:Wealth    -0.0600      0.320     -0.187      0.852      -0.697       0.577
Region[T.W]:Wealth    -0.3344      0.324     -1.031      0.306      -0.980       0.312
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        2.978   Durbin-Watson:                   1.786
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.226   Jarque-Bera (JB):                2.739
Skew:                          -0.359   Prob(JB):                        0.254
Kurtosis:                       2.491   Cond. No.                         818.
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

There are five unique `Region`s in the dataset: `['E' 'N' 'C' 'S' 'W']`

So, my question is, how does the model consider the effect of `Region:Wealth` interaction for the Region `C`? (`Region*Wealth` in that case would always be 0, no matter what the `Wealth` value is)

On the other hand, if we decide to not drop one of the dummy variables, then what about the dummy variable trap?

Comment: It is just a slope dummy; when C is the “base”, its effect is already in the coefficient of Wealth; other effects a considered relative to the base; you may change the base to see the non-zero coefficient of C region. The same logic applies to intercept: we see no C region shifter as well.

Comment: (thanks. alright, now suppose that I do this manually and add interaction terms to the dataframe (by multiplying `Wealth * Dummy_Var`. I end up with 4 interaction terms that are highly correlated with the main dummy variables (I tried this on two different datasets and got the correlations above 0.8). Normally, we would remove one of such highly collinear terms. If I do so and remove all of the dummy variables, I end up with the interaction terms only. 
Does it mean I could just use a new form of encoding in the first place? i.e using   `Wealth` and 0 instead of 1 and 0 for encoding?

Comment: Yes, I get that part, and interactions bring some degree of correlation by their nature, but I'm saying, if such an interaction term has a strong correlation with its corresponding dummy variable (let's say >0.9, which is the case in one of the datasets I'm working on), then shall I just consider removing either the dummy variable itself or the interaction term?

Comment: there is no "main" or "subordinated" dummy. Your model with 2 regions is a sort of $\alpha + \gamma_1 * D + (\beta + \gamma_2 * D) * X$ . So dummy_var `D` is the same, but your interaction term looks separate if you expand the expression.$D$ is coded 0 - for base region and 1 - for the second. If you add third region, you will need additional dummy $D_2$ and now you can encode 3 entities - `(0, 0)`, `(0,1)`, `(1,0)`.

Comment: I think we are talking about 2 different things. My question is what if a dummy variable has a high correlation (>0.9) with its interaction term, e.g. what if `Region[T.E]` and `Region[T.E]:Wealth` are highly correlated? Shall I then remove one of them to avoid multicollinearity? In some cases I have a correlation of 0.99 which is almost perfect multicollinearity

Comment: they should be correlated. Consider two cases with four regions each - your dummy (0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), and some interaction (0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6) or this, (0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 600)'. How can you get a low correlation with proper X in principle? 'almost perfect' is not perfect.

Comment: Alright then, so you are saying that only "perfect multicollinearity" is an issue and a correlation of e.g. `>0.9` (multicollinearity) should be ok. 
For regression analysis, I often have a feature selection method where I remove predictors which are highly correlated (I simply set a threshold of 0.8 or 0.9). I agree that there is no certain rules to deal with such cases, but sometimes if interpretability is v important (and not just the predictability), then I guess that'd be a common practice (to remove highly-correlated predictors, not necessarily perfect collinear ones). Don't you agree?

Comment: It’s a problematic terminology, but “no multicollinearity” usually means no perfect collinearity (you may see wikipedia article on this). Usual disclamer: everything depends on your data, your model and your purpose.